# Why does the quote be used before definition in Golang

Tags: go

I am studying `Golang` source code, I found [codes](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7b554575e46d1df9b68f71e051c8133aaf953fb7/src/net/http/server.go#L2283)

```
var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux

var defaultServeMux ServeMux
```

the quote is used before definition, I wrote a sample code like this but got error:

```
func main(){
    type ServeMux struct {
        hosts string
    }
    var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux
    var defaultServeMux ServeMux
    fmt.Printf("print [%s]\n", DefaultServeMux.hosts)
}
```

I got `undefined: defaultServeMux`

I want to know how can the codes compile successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first piece of code shows two package level variable declarations. Package level variable declarations are evaluated before `main` starts running based on the order imposed by dependencies. Because of this, in the first snippet, `defaultServeMux` is declared and initialized before `DefaultServeMux`.

When you declare variables in a function, they are evaluated in the order they are defined. Because of this, in the second code snippet, at the point where `DefaultServeMux` is declared, `defaultServeMux` is not yet defined.

Comment: I do not why does the author write like this? Why not put the definition first？